# Install php extension on AMPPS

Tags: php, php-extension, ampps

As the title says im trying to install a php extension (zip.so) that is missing from php7.1 version in ampps 3.8. I have searched for an answer but no luck so far.

Also using php5.6 and going to the php extensions list im able to see the zip extension, but since the software that im trying to intstall requires php 7.X im unable to simply use php5.6.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Do you have the `zip.so` for PHP 7? If so, have you enabled it in php.ini?

Comment: The zip.so is missing from the php.ini, even if i type it: extension=zip.so ,it gives an error saying thats not able to find it.

Comment: Then go to the ampps website and find where you can download the zip.so file for PHP 7.

Comment: Well i don't think you can actually download the .so file or at least i wasn't able to find a way to it, anyway i posted as an answer how to install extensions. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally found a way to do it:

1. Go to (for example) https://pecl.php.net/ and download the extension that you need.
2. Unzip the extension and go to the file location `$ cd my/extension`
3. Run phpize `/usr/local/ampps/php-7.1/bin/phpize`
4. Next run `./configure --with-php-config=/path/to/my/php-config` for example `./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/ampps/php-7.1/bin/php-config`
5. `make` and `sudo make install`
6. In the end of `sudo make install` log you will find this `Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/ampps/php-7.1/lib/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/` file path.
7. Go to the file path and you will find your compiled extension, for me it was `zip.so`
8. Finally copy the extension into your php folder `/usr/local/ampps/php-7.1/lib/extensions/ext` and you will be able to see it on the list of extensions in ampps, dont forget to enable it and restart apache2!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much Guillermo. This was very useful. I do not think i would have solved it by myself. Also for this particular issue this was the only answer that worked. I searched the net for more than 4 hours.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to do so

1. Open AMPPS Application ->Stop Apache (If running)

2 In "PHP" Tab -> "PHP Extension"

3. Enable "zip.so".
4. Apply
5. Restart Apache.

[See image for clarification I am using a mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBzYm.jpg)